# Matrix norm of product with diagonal does not factorize

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, numerical-methods, matrix-calculus, numerical-linear-algebra

Let $\|\cdot\| : \mathbb{R}^{n\times n} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}_+$ be the operator norm w.r.t. the $2$-norm on $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Do you have a quick counterexample to disprove that
$$
\|\Lambda A\| = \|\Lambda\|\|A\| \quad \text{ for all diagonal } \Lambda\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}\ ?
$$

(*Not* a homework question.)

Comment: It might not be a homework question, but it would still be helpful if you could include some [context](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question). What led you to ask this question? Any thoughts? What have you tried so far?

Comment: @BenGrossmann I derived a criterion of the form $\|\Lambda\|\|A\|< c$ with $\Lambda$ diagonal, which I'd like to include as a condition of an optimisation problem. It would be more efficient if (instead of a product of norms) this inequality could be written as $\|\Lambda A\|< c$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is no. As a counterexample, consider
$$
\Lambda = \pmatrix{1&0\\0&0}, A = \pmatrix{1 & 1\\ 1 & 1}.
$$
We have $\|\Lambda\| = 1, \|A\| = 2, \|\Lambda A\| = \sqrt{2}$.

Comment: Thanks. Don't suppose that $\Lambda$ invertible would help to restore multiplicativity?

Comment: It would not. If you add $I$ (the identity matrix) to both matrices (making them invertible), the equality still fails.

Comment: @fsp-b : Take $A=diag([2,1])$ and $Λ=diag([1,2])$. Then the operator norms of $A$, $Λ$ and $ΛA$ are all $2$.

Comment: Yes, and as $2\ne 2·2$, this claim is wrong. In general, $\|diag(v)\|_{op,2}=\|v\|_\infty$, and the max norm is not multiplicative under element-wise vector multiplication. So one can make even more simple counter-examples than yours with $A$ also a diagonal matrix.

Comment: @Lutz ...I need more coffee. Nice example.